# js.erb working locally but not in production

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, infinite-scroll, will-paginate

I followed the tutorial here http://railsforbeginners.com/chapters/chapter-9-infinite-scroll/ for an infinite scrolling. The code works good locally but when I deploy it to prod. the pagination links (1 2 3 4) still show and the infinite scrolling doesn't fire. I also tried to add these files in `assets.rb` with no success

First of I'm using `Rails 4`, my `application.js` looks like this

```
//= require jquery2
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui.min
//= require bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require select2
//= require infinite_scroll
//= require turbolinks
```

`Controller action`

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js { render "visitors/index" }
end
```

`index.js.erb`

```
$('#my-articles').append('<%= j render @articles %>');
<% if @articles.next_page %>
$('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @articles %>');
add_tweets();
<% else %>
$(window).off('scroll');
$('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>



function add_tweets(){
  <% @articles.each do |article|%>
    handle_open_modal("<%= article.id %>");
  <%end%>

}
```

Comment: How about looking into web developer tools and checking for 404 in network tab there?

Comment: Can you remove turbolinks from your app and check

Comment: Can you please add production.rb file configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to get it working using 
[This Reference](https://www.sitepoint.com/infinite-scrolling-rails-basics/)

I removed turbolinks and all it's reference

Then added this to the `index.html.erb` without have to use `jQuery $(document).on('ready`

```
if ($('#infinite-scrolling').size() > 0){
        $(window).on('scroll', function(){
          var more_posts_url = $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href')
          heights = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 500
            if(more_posts_url && $(window).scrollTop() > heights){
                $('.pagination').html('<img src="/assets/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." title="Loading..." />')
                $.getScript(more_posts_url)
            }
        });
    }
```

Then all the `*.js.erb` start working.

I was trying to avoid removing turbolinks but done trying to get it working with it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `assets.rb`

Try this line:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['Index.js']
```

-> Rails may only reference files by their (non ERB) asset filename

also as a matter of style you should lowercase the filename to:  `index.js.erb`

Comment: As I mentioned above, I did try `assets.rb` file including your solution without luck. Also the CAP in index is just a typo. Thanks for trying

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that jQuery is loading? As suggested above by going to developers tool Network and reloading.
Do your assets precompile in production environment?
Make sure you have this config.serve_static_assets = true in your config/application.rb
For Heroku and Rails 4 see [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline)

Comment: Jquery was loaded fine and all the assets were added correctly. As I found previously on SOF and Google